# Is the free() method being called inadvertently on my DataObject?

Tags: developer

This behaviour happens on a certain environment, but not on another. I am trying to work out why.

There is [a while loop in CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::deliver()](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.27/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php#L550) that cycles through emails to be delivered.

I noticed that the loop was ending prematurely. I tracked this down to some custom code I had addes that was adding a token. In this code, I was calling MailingJob.getsingle.

It turns out that many calls to the API and it seems other methods too will cause the loop to end prematurely.

The simplest proof of concept I came up with was

```
var_dump($eq->N);
while ($eq->fetch()) {
  civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get');
  var_dump($eq->N);
  var_dump($eq->fetch());exit;
```

which outputs

```
int(50)
int(50)
bool(false)
```

which is madness, I am sure you will agree.

Do you have any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware that the system had been patched with https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10844/files. Reversing the patch resolved the problem.

Comment: alternative at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11614